# Kotlin for loops

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to learn kotlin language (especially for android) but i found some difficulty to learn various types of for loop so what are the difference between normal for loop, for each loop and for each indexed and how to use it?

For example in this article: https://medium.com/mindorks/building-a-customview-tictactoe-eb439f506505 (that talks about android custom view), there is this part:

```
        squares.forEachIndexed {
        i, rects ->
        for ((j, rect) in rects.withIndex()) {
            if (rect.contains(x.toInt(), y.toInt()))
                return Pair(i, j)
            }
        }
```

where he use for each indexedto iterate through all the variables contained in squares (that is a 2d array) but i really don't understand how it works.
Thanks to anyone who helps me!

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops

Comment: Yes but there isn't a good explanation of the argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some alternatives:

1. Use `forEachIndexed`:

   ```
   myList.forEachIndexed { i, element ->
       println(i)
       println(element)
   }
   ```
2. The extension `withIndex` on `Iterable` types that can be used in `for`-each:

   ```
   val ints = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

   for ((i, e) in ints.withIndex()) {
       println("$i: $e")
   }
   ```
3. And then there's an extension property `indices` on `Collection`, `Array` etc., which comes near to a common `for` as known from C, Java etc:

   ```
   for(i in ints.indices){
        println("$i: ${ints[i]}")
   }
   ```

**EDIT** (response to comment):

Of course, `forEachIndexed` can be used on a multidimensional array, too:

```
val twoDim: Array<IntArray> = ...

twoDim.forEachIndexed { i, innerArr ->               
    innerArr.forEachIndexed { j, val ->                
        println("$i,$j -> $val")              
    }                                                 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering soon, I have a question: can I use withIndex on a 2d array? And if yes what happens?

Comment: Sure, see the EDIT

Comment: Ok but what if j is the index and rect the var where is stored the value of the equivalent rects, it will iterate through all the variables of the array also if it's bidimensional? And for example when he iterate through rects[0] [1] what value will j have?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have marked your answer as correct and thank you again for the help